# Cannot update nor remove mariadb

Tags: software-installation, updates, mysql, uninstall, mariadb

I made a mistake. I had to update mariadb from 10.0 to 10.2
So did:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mariadb-server
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install'
  to correct these: 
The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
   mariadb-client : Depends: mariadb-client-10.0 (=10.0.33+maria-1~trusty) but 10.0.31-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 is to be installed
   mariadb-server : Depends: mariadb-server-10.2 (>=    10.2.7+maria~xenial) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

And then tried to remove as I got errors:

```
Reading package lists...Done 
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   mariadb-client : Depends: mariadb-client-10.0 (=10.0.33+maria-1~trusty) but 10.0.31-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

`sudo apt-get -f install` gives me:

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
Correcting dependencies... Done 
The following additional packages will be installed:   
  mariadb-client-10.0 mariadb-client-core-10.0 mariadb-server-10.0 mariadb-server-core-10.0
Suggested packages:   mailx mariadb-test tinyca
Recommended packages:  libhtml-template-perl 
The following packages will be upgraded:
  mariadb-client-10.0 mariadb-client-core-10.0 mariadb-server-10.0 mariadb-server-core-10.0 
4 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 26 not upgraded. 
4 not fully installed or removed. 
Need to get 0 B/11,7 MB of archives. 
After this operation, 9709 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ... (Reading database ... 304724 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mariadb-server-10.0_10.0.33+maria-1~trusty_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mariadb-server-10.0 (10.0.33+maria-1~trusty) over (10.0.31-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-server-10.0_10.0.33+maria-1~trusty_amd64.deb 
  (--unpack):  trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man1/mysql_upgrade.1.gz', which is also in package mariadb-server-core-10.0 10.0.31-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
dpkg: regarding .../mariadb-server-core-10.0_10.0.33+maria-1~trusty_amd64.deb containing mariadb-server-core-10.0:
 mariadb-server-10.0 conflicts with mysql-server-core-5.5   mariadb-server-core-10.0
 provides mysql-server-core-5.5 and is to be installed.

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-server-core-10.0_10.0.33+maria-1~trusty_amd64.deb
  (--unpack):  
conflicting packages - not installing mariadb-server-core-10.0 
dpkg: regarding .../mariadb-client-core-10.0_10.0.33+maria-1~trusty_amd64.deb containing mariadb-client-core-10.0:  
mariadb-client-10.0 conflicts with mysql-client-core-5.5   
mariadb-client-core-10.0 provides mysql-client-core-5.5 and is to be installed.

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-client-core-10.0_10.0.33+maria-1~trusty_amd64.deb (--unpack):  
conflicting packages - not installing mariadb-client-core-10.0 dpkg: regarding .../mariadb-client-10.0_10.0.33+maria-1~trusty_amd64.deb containing mariadb-client-10.0:  
mariadb-client-core-10.0 conflicts with mysql-client-5.5   
mariadb-client-10.0 provides mysql-client-5.5 and is to be installed.

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-client-10.0_10.0.33+maria-1~trusty_amd64.deb (--unpack):  
conflicting packages - not installing mariadb-client-10.0 
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ... 
Errors were encountered while processing:  /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-server-10.0_10.0.33+maria-1~trusty_amd64.deb 
/var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-server-core-10.0_10.0.33+maria-1~trusty_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-client-core-10.0_10.0.33+maria-1~trusty_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-client-10.0_10.0.33+maria-1~trusty_amd64.deb 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm stuck, cannot install, cannot remove, cannot update.

What should I do?

---

That gives me the following:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these: 
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libmysqlclient20 : 
Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.5) but it is not going to be installed  mariadb-client : 
Depends: mariadb-client-10.0 (= 10.0.33+maria-1~trusty) but 10.0.31-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 is to be installed  mariadb-common : 
Depends: mysql-common (>= 10.0.33+maria-1~trusty) but it is not going to be installed  mariadb-server : 
Depends: mariadb-server-10.0 (= 10.0.33+maria-1~trusty) but 10.0.31-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 is to be installed E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: I read mariadb should be removed first but that fails to, because of dependencies

Comment: Try these `sudo systemctl stop mysql`, `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, then `sudo apt purge "mysql*"`

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -f`? Thanks.

Comment: @george result = "The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libmysqlclient20 :"

Comment: @DavidFoerster, That did the trick, thanks :). Mariadb is nod updated

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there are newer versions available for the packages that you want to install that depend on equally newer versions of packages that are already installed. Apt doesn't know how to fix this unless you tell it to upgrade all these packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -f
```

Comment: As you’ve never accepted an answer before: if this answers your question, don’t forget to click the grey ☑ under the number at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means “yes, this answer is valid”!

Comment: David, thanks. I was having a problem updating Ubuntu 16.04. I was using 'sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade' and the process just kept stalling when it got to MariaDB 10.2. Your suggestion 'sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -f ' fixed the problem presumably due to the explanation you provide. Brilliant, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

Before doing:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove "mysql*"
```

I've tried on my laptop and it worked.

Please note that any custom configs that were added after the install will still be there.